APT broken due to broken python libraries
I am on Debian 12.
I made a rookie error installing python libraries (numpy, pandas, sklearn) using apt and now whenever i try to install or uninstall anything i get this error.
When installing
thedude@192:~$ sudo apt install sl
[sudo] password for thedude: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-bottleneck : Depends: python3-numpy (>= 1:1.22.0) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: python3-numpy-abi9
 python3-contourpy : Depends: python3-numpy but it is not going to be installed
 python3-matplotlib : Depends: python3-numpy (>= 1:1.22.0) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: python3-numpy-abi9
 python3-numexpr : Depends: python3-numpy (>= 1:1.22.0) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python3-numpy-abi9
 python3-pandas : Depends: python3-numpy but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: python3-numpy (>= 1:1.18.5~) but it is not going to be installed or
                           python3 (< 3.10) but 3.11.2-1+b1 is to be installed
 python3-pandas-lib : Depends: python3-numpy (>= 1:1.22.0) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: python3-numpy-abi9
                      Recommends: python3-numba but it is not going to be installed
 python3-pythran : Depends: python3-numpy but it is not going to be installed
 python3-scipy : Depends: python3-numpy (>= 1:1.22.0) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: python3-numpy-abi9
 python3-sklearn : Depends: python3-numpy but it is not going to be installed
 python3-sklearn-lib : Depends: python3-numpy (>= 1:1.22.0) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: python3-numpy-abi9
 python3-tables : Depends: python3-numpy but it is not going to be installed
 python3-tables-lib : Depends: python3-numpy (>= 1:1.22.0) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: python3-numpy-abi9
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

When Uninstalling:
thedude@192:~$ sudo apt remove python3-numpy
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package 'python3-numpy' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-bottleneck : Depends: python3-numpy (>= 1:1.22.0) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: python3-numpy-abi9
 python3-contourpy : Depends: python3-numpy but it is not going to be installed
 python3-matplotlib : Depends: python3-numpy (>= 1:1.22.0) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: python3-numpy-abi9
 python3-numexpr : Depends: python3-numpy (>= 1:1.22.0) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python3-numpy-abi9
 python3-pandas : Depends: python3-numpy but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: python3-numpy (>= 1:1.18.5~) but it is not going to be installed or
                           python3 (< 3.10) but 3.11.2-1+b1 is to be installed
 python3-pandas-lib : Depends: python3-numpy (>= 1:1.22.0) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: python3-numpy-abi9
                      Recommends: python3-numba but it is not going to be installed
 python3-pythran : Depends: python3-numpy but it is not going to be installed
 python3-scipy : Depends: python3-numpy (>= 1:1.22.0) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: python3-numpy-abi9
 python3-sklearn : Depends: python3-numpy but it is not going to be installed
 python3-sklearn-lib : Depends: python3-numpy (>= 1:1.22.0) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: python3-numpy-abi9
 python3-tables : Depends: python3-numpy but it is not going to be installed
 python3-tables-lib : Depends: python3-numpy (>= 1:1.22.0) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: python3-numpy-abi9
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

I tried apt fix-broken install as the error message suggests.
thedude@192:~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fonts-lato icu-devtools libclang-cpp14 libffi-dev libicu-dev libllvm14
  libncurses-dev libpfm4 libtinfo-dev libxml2-dev libz3-dev
  llvm-14-linker-tools llvm-14-runtime llvm-14-tools nss-plugin-pem
  python3-yaml sphinx-rtd-theme-common
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  python3-numpy
Suggested packages:
  gfortran
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python3-numpy
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 27 not upgraded.
Need to get 5,209 kB of archives.
After this operation, 28.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 python3-numpy amd64 1:1.24.2-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 146.75.54.132 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/n/numpy/python3-numpy_1.24.2-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 146.75.54.132 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

My understanding is that the library that is generating the error is numpy.
I found out that it is installed by typing:
thedude@192:~$ sudo apt list python3-numpy
Listing... Done
python3-numpy/stable 1:1.24.2-1 amd64

But as shown I cant remove it.
I tried updating and also --fix-missing and also autoremove
thedude@192:~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install --fix-missing
[sudo] password for thedude: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fonts-lato icu-devtools libclang-cpp14 libffi-dev libicu-dev libllvm14
  libncurses-dev libpfm4 libtinfo-dev libxml2-dev libz3-dev
  llvm-14-linker-tools llvm-14-runtime llvm-14-tools nss-plugin-pem
  python3-yaml sphinx-rtd-theme-common
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  python3-numpy
Suggested packages:
  gfortran
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python3-numpy
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 27 not upgraded.
Need to get 5,209 kB of archives.
After this operation, 28.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 python3-numpy amd64 1:1.24.2-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 146.75.54.132 80]
Unable to correct missing packages.
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/n/numpy/python3-numpy_1.24.2-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 146.75.54.132 80]
E: Aborting install.

Tried update works fine but makes no differenze.
Is there anything i can do to fix this?

Are you sure you used apt and not pip to install these?

@Panki if they’d been installed with pip, apt wouldn’t complain about them.

Yes, using apt was the mistake. I am not really getting wich variables i sould delete... i confirm i Tried updating buy didn't solve

Try sudo appt update as MatsK answer suggests. Always use apt update before doing anything else with APT. deb.debian.org is a mirror redirector, so it will find the closest mirror to you. When I copied and pasted the IP from your output in Chrome, I got a Fastly Mirror Error. If after running apt update the redirector still chooses that IP as the closest, the mirror needs to be reported, and we need to manually set a mirror in your apt.sources file

I Tried what eyoung100 suggested and still installing isn't working, also looked up to  /var/lib/apt/lists/ but didn't find anything clearly related that i would be confident to remove

@eyoung100 getting a mirror error is perfectly normal, the server doesn’t know what domain you’re asking for if you just use the IP address.

"Yes, using apt was the mistake." - No, using apt to install numpy is totally fine. I'm not sure what caused the problem you were seeing, and it's unlikely we can debug that now that you forcibly removed the package information. One thing I do notice is that apt was trying to download numpy 1:1.24.2-1, which has been superseded by 1:1.24.2-1+deb12u1 way back in June (and hence the 404). An apt update should solve that, but you commented elsewhere that that din't work for you.

Yes, the fact It was trying to download  and obsolete vefsion was something i noticed but I didn't have the knowelage to understand that It was my problem, First time i really use Linux as main.

Credits to @Stephen Kitt that suggested this answer in the comments.
I solved doing
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*_*
sudo apt update
sudo apt --fix-broken install


Congratulations, wait 48 hours and mark your own answer for a reputation gain.  Welcome to the U&L Exchange

The essence of the “404 Not Found” error. It’s an HTTP status code that indicates the requested resource could not be found on the server. In the context of apt-get, this means that the package you’re trying to access isn’t found in the repository server.
Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 python3-numpy amd64 1:1.24.2-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 146.75.54.132 80]

Run sudo apt update and then try again to install python3-numpy.
It is also a good habit to run sudo apt update and then sudo apt upgrade before installing packages.

Tried, still getting the same errors, Update works but then i can't install.

And did you do a upgrade?
